# How to find a bad update, i.e. revert to version of a specific date and then step forward

Tags: 14.04, networking, updates, vpn

Pursuant to this issue:

[Can't connect to VPN on 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545312/cant-connect-to-vpn-on-14-04-lts)

So the last time my VPN client worked was ~20 days ago. I checked with the ISP and they say "No problem", I checked with my company's help desk and they say, "No problem", I've checked and re-checked my credentials and there's no apparent problem there. In any case there is a specific error when credentials are wrong and I'm getting a generic one. "Connection failed".

My current theory, which I want to test, is that it's a bad update. I want to revert all updates back to 20 days ago and then step forward so I can find out exactly which version or series of updates is causing trouble. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I found was some behavior I think is not supported by the Linux clients.  I loaded a Windows 7 VM and the stock Cisco VPN client. When I ran it from Windows, I was prompted for all the usual but afterwards there was an additional prompt for "The Next" RSA key after the one that I had used. So what I think happened is that this behavior was triggered by a Windows password change and it is not supported in the Linux clients.

**Work around:** When you change your Windows password, immediately log in to the VPN from any Windows machine to eliminate the behavior.