# can't set up a vpnc connection with network-manager on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: vpnc

My VPN connection is not working for me on a clean install of Kubuntu 15.04, and it was on 14.10 and earlier versions. I can set up a connection via the "connection editor", but when I want to connect it flashes up a window that is probably where I should type the passwords (but it's gone immediately, so I can't tell). After saying for a while that it is connecting, it gives up. Syslog looks like this:

```
grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog
Jul  9 15:12:11 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Jul  9 15:12:11 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 2136
Jul  9 15:12:11 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: ureadahead:NetworkManager_new.1445: Ignored relative path
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: ureadahead:NetworkManager: Ignored relative path
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: message repeated 3 times: [ ureadahead:NetworkManager: Ignored relative path]
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: ureadahead:NetworkManager_new.1490: Ignored relative path
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: ureadahead:NetworkManager: Ignored relative path
Jul  9 15:12:15 hostname ureadahead[307]: message repeated 2 times: [ ureadahead:NetworkManager: Ignored relative path]
Jul  9 15:14:11 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <error> [1436447651.584396] [vpn-manager/nm-vpn-connection.c:1778] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
```

Creating a connection with the passwords in the configuration didn't help either: 
    Jul  9 16:46:17 hostname NetworkManager[811]:  [1436453177.020663] [vpn-manager/nm-vpn-connection.c:1778] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.

I have tried manually creating a conf file, which seemed to be partially successful. `ifconfig` had an extra item called `tun0`, I could ping websites using URLs, but couldn't load any websites in my browser. This might be an indication that my problem similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576080/vpnc-works-but-network-manager-vpnc-fails), but not quite, because not having websites working is quite a restriction. This is what I did there:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo vpnc-connect /etc/vpnc/my_vpn_config.conf
[sudo] password for user: 
Enter IPSec secret for groupname@123.123.123.123: 
Enter password for user@123.123.123.123:
VPNC started in background (pid: 19663)...
user@hostname:~$ ping askubuntu.com
PING askubuntu.com (122.122.122.122) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 122.122.122.122: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=51.1 ms
user@hostname:~$ sudo vpnc-disconnect
Terminating vpnc daemon (pid: 19663)
```

the syslog for this connection looks like this:

```
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): carrier is OFF
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): new Tun device (driver: 'unknown' ifindex: 6)
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): link connected
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) starting connection 'tun0'
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jul  9 16:15:54 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (tun0) successful, device activated.
Jul  9 16:17:49 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
Jul  9 16:17:49 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> (tun0): deactivating device (reason 'removed') [36]
Jul  9 16:17:49 hostname NetworkManager[811]: <info> devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
```

`kvpnc` gives `error: Timeout while connecting to 123.123.123.123. vpnc connect process will be killed.` Pinging the gateway returns within 50ms.

I'm not too sure what else to try. Other options (pptp, openconnect, openvpn) seem to require a CA certificate, which I don't have, so I assume I'm stuck with vpnc. Hopefully someone out there will have some ideas?

**Edit:** it seems to be a variant of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1297849), although the fix there didn't work for me.