# How to check that VPNC (VPN Cisco) works on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, network-manager, vpn

I connect with VPNC and get the message:

*VPN connection was successfully established.*

and a *lock* in the WiFi icon in the upper-right corner of Ubuntu Desktop appears.

How to check that VPNC really works?

---

More about this problem:

I've just got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04 and all its updates. Before installing/configuring anything else, I tried to ssh to our local server secured with VPNC. I just installed VPNC following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps): which really installs the package called `network-manager-vpnc`. Then I establish VPNC connection, and get the message about the success and the lock on the WiFi icon.

Then I try to ssh to the server. But I get an error, which is the same as if VPNC was *not* on:

```
ssh: connect to host “xxx” port 22: Connection timed out
```

It seems to me that the lock signals a functioning VPNC, but the VPNC actually does not work.

Note that:

- When I try to establish the VPNC connection (by clicking on the WiFi icon,
  then VPN Connections, and then on 'Some of My VPNC Connection Names') nothing
  happens. I need to try several times before the WiFi icon starts
  flashing. The flashing is then reliably followed be the appearance of the
  lock, which remains there and does not go. But, again, to get it
  flashing may take several attempts.
- I tried two installations of Ubuntu 14.04 on two different laptops (3
  laptops in total). The were installed from different USB sticks/CDs
  and downloaded and created at different times. The problem is the
  same on all laptops: *Connection timed out*.
- Also I tried another two laptops of my colleague, both running Ubuntu
  14.04. I could ssh via VPNC without any problems using my details. More on that is
  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654286/ssh-and-vpn-cisco-connection-working-on-one-laptop-but-not-on-another-both-lapt?noredirect=1#comment940822_654286).

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by only connecting via `vpnc` and not using `network-manager-vpnc`. Look at the reply by seedkhan [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps) or my reply [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654286/ssh-and-vpn-cisco-connection-working-on-one-laptop-but-not-on-another-both-lapt/682116#682116). The fact that `vpnc` works but not with `network-manager-vpnc` on a freshly installed ubuntu suggests that there may be a bug in `network-manager-vpnc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by running `ifconfig` and checking for VPN related entries (usually `tun0` or `pptp0` or something similar). Alternatively, there are a number of websites which will display your IP address as they see it, e.g. [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20ip%20address). Switch the VPN connection on & off, and check whether the address changes.

(See also my [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646441/cant-set-up-a-vpnc-connection-with-network-manager-on-kubuntu-15-04) and a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1297849) which has similar symptoms. Following the troubleshooting procedures from that bug report may help you further.)